# matplotlib Plot does not appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I am using python v3.6 with pycharm and anaconda. I tried to run the code below to plot a simple sine wave;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a sequence of numbers from -10 to 10 with 100 steps in between
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
# Create a second array using sine
y = np.sin(x)
# The plot function makes a line chart of one array against another
plt.plot(x, y, marker="x")
pass
```

The code runs smoothly without error but no plot appears. How do I get the plot to appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `plt.show()` at the end.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a sequence of numbers from -10 to 10 with 100 steps in between
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
# Create a second array using sine
y = np.sin(x)
# The plot function makes a line chart of one array against another
plt.plot(x, y, marker="x")
plt.show()
pass
```

or, if you want to save it into a file

```
plt.savefig("my_file.png")
```

Comment: Thanks. I will mark it as the answer. cannot upvote due to lack of points.